# Is there a way to migrate blobstore keys generated via create_gs_key to a new gcs bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We have an application on Google Appengine that we are migrating to a new app_id and region.

We've transferred datastore entities successfully and migrated cloud storage files to a new bucket but have run into an issue when reading blob_keys.

Part of our code uses the blobstore.create_gs_key functionality however, now that we've moved to a new cloud storage bucket, the blob_keys generated via "blobstore.create_gs_key" no longer work.

Is there a way to migrate these keys to use a new bucket?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, since `blobstore.create_gs_key()` takes as argument a Cloud Storage file name in the format `/gs/bucket/object_name` the blob_keys generated for objects in the old bucket won't be usable in the new app, as you already observed.

You'd have to generate new blob_keys for each object. If you actually stored the old blob_keys (for example as datastore entity properties) you'd have to update them.

Since apparently you can't obtain the actual object name from the blob_key you'd need to iterate through all the (relevant) objects in the GS bucket, generating the old and new blob_keys for each of them, searching for all stored references to the old blob_key values and replacing them with the new blob_key values.

It's unclear to me if `blobstore.create_gs_key()` will actually generate the *same* blob_keys for the *same* GS object in both apps. It should be easy for you to check since you already have the related code in both apps. If it doesn't then the `object_name` <-> old `blob_key` mapping needs to be obtained in the old app and passed to the new app for replacing the old blob_keys with their new corresponding values, since in this case the new app would not be able to generate the old blob_keys.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, that makes sense. I haven't tested it yet but sounds correct.